# How to use funcall on a method to set an attribute of an object

Tags: oop, common-lisp

Considering this code:

```
(defclass test () ((test :initform nil :accessor test)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS TEST>
(defvar *test* (make-instance 'test))
*TEST*
```

and this test:

```
(funcall #'test *test*)
nil
```

one would expect that this works:

```
(setf (funcall #'test *test*) 123)
```

the same as

```
(setf (test *test*) 123)
123
```

but it results in this:

```
; in: LAMBDA NIL
;     (FUNCALL #'(SETF FUNCALL) #:NEW1175 #:TMP1177 #:TMP1176)
; ==>
;   (SB-C::%FUNCALL #'(SETF FUNCALL) #:NEW1175 #:TMP1177 #:TMP1176)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   The function (SETF FUNCALL) is undefined, and its name is reserved by ANSI CL
;   so that even if it were defined later, the code doing so would not be portable.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     (SETF FUNCALL)
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

Why doesn't it work, and how can I work around it?

I tested it using either SBCL and CLISP with the same result.

Comment: Note you've got a typo in your code example (`declass`). When asking questions, you should always copy and paste in the code / output that you have tried, otherwise a silly typo might have a responder chasing up completely the wrong tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SETF` is a special form (see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aa.htm for the part of the spec explaining it). Your second example works because the lisp implementation interprets `(test *test*)` syntactically.

To see what's going on, look at this session:

```
This is SBCL 1.0.56.0.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (defclass test () ((test :initform nil :accessor test)))

#<STANDARD-CLASS TEST>
* (defvar *test* (make-instance 'test))

*TEST*
* (macroexpand '(setf (test *test*) 123))

(LET* ((#:*TEST*606 *TEST*))
  (MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND (#:NEW605)
      123
    (FUNCALL #'(SETF TEST) #:NEW605 #:*TEST*606)))
T
* #'(setf test)

#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION (SETF TEST) (1)>
* (macroexpand '(setf (funcall #'test *test*) 123))

(LET* ((#:G609 #'TEST) (#:*TEST*608 *TEST*))
  (MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND (#:NEW607)
      123
    (FUNCALL #'(SETF FUNCALL) #:NEW607 #:G609 #:*TEST*608)))
T
```

Note that the first macroexpansion grabs `#'(setf test)`, which is the writer function that gets automatically defined by your `defclass` call. The second blindly translates to `#'(setf funcall)`, which doesn't exist (hence the error).

To answer your "how can I work around it?" question, we'd probably need to know more about what you're trying to do. For example, you could use something like `(setf (slot-value object slot-name))` which would allow you to choose the slot programmatically.

Comment: i want to dynamically setf slot values depending on how many different information (in a list) are given therefore the accessors are saved in a list which is iterated through parallel to the argument list e.g. `(list #'accessor1 #'accessor2) (list value1 value2)`: going through both lists which will result in `(setf (funcall #'accessor1 obj) value1)` and `(setf (funcall #'accessor2 obj) value2)`. Macro wouldn't work because the amount of values given is not known before runtime.

Comment: I think Rainer's answer probably has a solution to what you need but if you haven't got writers defined on each slot, another approach might be something like the following: `(defun multiple-slot-setf (object slots values) (mapc (lambda (slot value) (setf (slot-value object slot) value)) slots values))`

Answer (score 2):

The `:accessor` slot option defines two functions: `FOO` to read the slot value and `(SETF FOO)` to set the slot value. Note that in the latter case in Common Lisp the function name is not a symbol, but a list.

If you want to have a list of functions and values (your comment), then your list needs to contain the setter functions.

```
(defclass test ()
 ((foo :initform nil :accessor foo)
  (bar :initform nil :accessor bar)))

(map nil
     (lambda (function argument)
       (funcall function argument object))
     (list #'(setf foo) #'(setf bar))
     (list arg1 arg2))
```